Python basic summation vs the built-in sum function
I'm trying to benchmark some algorithms on floating point numbers using the asymptotics expansion of the harmonic sum: H_n = ln(n) + gamma + o(1), where gamma is the Euler-Mascheroni constant (approximatively equals to 0.5772156).
First of all, I've coded three easy functions computing this summation in the more naive way:
def basic(n):
    s = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        s += 1 / i
    return s - math.log(n) - 0.577215664901532861

def with_sum(n):
    s = sum(1 / i for i in range(1, n + 1))
    return s - math.log(n) - 0.577215664901532861

def with_numpy_sum(n):
    s = np.sum(1 / i for i in range(1, n + 1))
    return s - math.log(n) - 0.577215664901532861

I thought that the Python built-in function sum was coded in C and the numpy built-in function np.sum was even more optimised.
But, surprinsingly, I've obtained the following timers:
>>> N = 100000000
>>> timeit basic(N)
4.91 s ± 263 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> timeit with_sum(N)
5.61 s ± 360 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> timeit with_numpy_sum(N)
7.83 s ± 210 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

What I thought to be faster turns out to become slower...!
Does anyone is able to explain this?
I've seen a similar question, but I'm not able to compute 1 / i without a for loop...

Without a for loop: a = 1/np.arange(1,n+1)

For the numpy version, you should really use numpy functions, not the range object: np.sum(np.arange(1, n+1)/1) - np.log(n) - 0.577215664901532861

Besides the time taken, have you checked the answer that you get? (Consider the summation order.)

@jared Thanks! That's very nice. Now the timer is less than a second:
828 ms ± 55.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

@lastchance Yes, of course. That is exactly what I want to do, as well as using Kahan algorithm summation

Generators are memory-efficient, not time-efficient. Iterating over range is a constant across all three versions, but iterating over the generator (1/i for i in range(1, n+1)) is an additional level of overhead not present in basic.
If you take the time to build a concrete list in memory first, then pass that to sum, you'll see it outperforming with_sum and being competitive with basic (at least for smaller values of N, before the cost of building the list before iterating over it becomes a lost cause).

I imagine it is due to you using a generator type inside the numpy call. If you look into the source code for numpy.sum you can see that for non-numpy type objects there is a a reduction step before the sum. My guess that the reduction step for generators is expensive.
It's difficult to answer concretely without knowing the python/NumPy version. I find it kind of interesting in python 3.11.7 / numpy 1.26.4 they spit out a warning and use python default sum under the hood when using generators:
// Stub from fromnumeric.py in the np.sum 
 ...
    if isinstance(a, _gentype):
        # 2018-02-25, 1.15.0
        warnings.warn(
            "Calling np.sum(generator) is deprecated, and in the future will give a different result. "
            "Use np.sum(np.fromiter(generator)) or the python sum builtin instead.",
            DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)

        res = _sum_(a)
        if out is not None:
            out[...] = res
            return out
        return res
 ...

